# Taxonomy vs Post Status

Tags: taxonomy, performance, post-status

I'm building a web app so scalability is one of my main focuses when developing.

On the app I am building I have a post type called 'Projects'. A project can be either be:

- Open
- In Work
- On Hold
- Completed

I don't really need any kind of UI, just the ability to query for all projects that are in one or more of those statuses.

I assume since post_status is in the posts table that it's going to be quicker using this method to perform those queries rather than use a taxonomy to do so?

So my question is which would be faster to query if there were 100,000 projects - Post Status or a Taxonomy?

Cheers

Comment: I'd assume the same for the same reasoning. To be 100% sure you'll probably need to try it yourself.

Comment: The `posts_request` filter should give you the used SQL. You could simply time the output there or try to run it via Adminer or phpMyAdmin to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably post_status but this answer is probably irrelevant in your case. You have your own application with its own usage pattern of the DB therefor the assumptions used when designing wordpress DB for use by core might not fit you. Maybe you will need to add another index to the posts table, maybe create optimized table of your own.

Caching is also an important factor. If the data set does not change frequently then good caching scheme will make the speed difference irrelevant.

This question sounds like an attempt in early optimization. My suggestion is that you use the built-in tools (post meta data in this case might be better then taxonomy) to get your application running and then you can profile it and solve the real bottle necks and not the imaginary ones.